# Is the http-proxy tag off-topic?

Tags: discussion, tagging

There is an [http-proxy](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/http-proxy) tag. Aren't both the subjects of HTTP and proxy servers off-topic? Did this used to be on-topic and we are keeping it for historical reasons?

Answer (score 5):

I would say it depends on the exact context of the question, but in most cases, yes, discussions about a proxy would be off topic. (as it's almost entirely a server or software discussion.)

How to direct traffic *to* your proxy would be an example of an on-topic use. (i.e. WCCP, policy routing, etc.)

Comment: So overall the tag is worth keeping for the cases where it is on topic?

Comment: heh, or to find off-topic stuff